# Patterns - Matcher.group() vs Matcher.pattern().pattern()

Tags: java, regex

I'm a bit confused about the difference between the following:

```
Matcher m;
m.group();
```

and

```
Matcher m;
m.pattern().pattern();
```

They both return the correct match from the list but I don't understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Completely different things.

- `Matcher.pattern().pattern()` returns the `String` representation of the `Pattern` from which this `Matcher` has been initialized against an input text.
- `Matcher.group()` returns the main group matcher (index 0) **if** there is a match of the given `Pattern` against the given text

`Matcher.group()` will throw an `IllegalStateException` if no match is found, i.e. if not wrapped in a `matcher.find()` boolean condition.

The `Matcher.group(int i)` overloads let you specify a group index for the explicit groups you define in your `Pattern` (1-based), in their hierarchical order of appearance (with parenthesis).

Those overloads will throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` if the indexed group is not defined in your `Pattern`.

**Example**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+");
String input = "blah";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    System.out.println(m.pattern().pattern());
}
```

**Output**

```
blah
.+
```

**More**

API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).